# How to Windows 10 MKLINK without deletion or rename original folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, office365, symbolic-link, windows-libraries

Microsoft Office 365, by default, do not show custom Libraries created with Windows 10 File Explorer. I am advised to use mklink as workaround but need help on the steps.

According to[workaround for Office 365](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/windows-10-how-to-show-custom-libaries-in-office/16a26913-0951-4b67-9041-78b3ef54b913?messageId=946dd8d6-09d5-4fc2-ab3b-219f8bbd88e8)

However, is the following assertion true that delete or rename is mandatory ?

[Delete or Rename mandatory](https://superuser.com/questions/1600225/creating-a-mklink-to-a-folder-on-windows-10)

Comment: In this you dont delete or rename them.  You need the original ones there.  In the other example, they were being shifted.

Comment: My guess is you won't have to because it sounds like you're creating a new entry rather than modifying an existing one